# Изменение стилей на основе значения Select

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Код:

```
<select class="select" id="aitype">
<option selected disabled>Выберите тип</option>
<option value="0">Тип 1</option>
<option value="1">Тип 2</option>
</select>

<div class="title">Выбрано</div>
```

Задача, если в Select выбрано значение Тип 2 (value 1), скрыть идущий далее  `<div class="title">Выбрано</div>`.

Как это сделать? Использую бутстрап. Так же было бы желательно, на чистом CSS.

Пытался сам:

```
#aitype[value="0"] ~ .title {
display: none;
}
```

Не работает.

Comment: На чистом CSS, интересно. Тут условие надо. JS нужен, чтоб проверить.

Comment: У `select` нет аттрибута `value`. Трюк по аналогии с кастомизированным чекбоксом не пройдет, тк на css выбранный элемент селекта можно поймать только так - `#aitype option[value="0"]:checked { display: none; }`, и подняться вверх уже нельзя

Answer (score 1):

Проще на jquery:

```js
$('#aitype').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == 1) {
 $('.title').css('display','none');
  }
  else {
    $('.title').css('display','block');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<select class="select" id="aitype">
<option selected disabled>Выберите тип</option>
<option value="0">Тип 1</option>
<option value="1">Тип 2</option>
</select>

<div class="title">Выбрано</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select class="select" id="aitype" onchange="this.nextElementSibling.hidden = this.value == 1;">
        <option selected disabled>Выберите тип</option>
        <option value="0">Тип 1</option>
        <option value="1">Тип 2</option>
    </select>

    <div class="title">Выбрано</div>
```